# when I multiply a number-byte size and another number the same size the result is a word..How could i save it

Tags: assembly

This is my code..But I have an error and I don't know how to correct it. There is a mistake when i try to multiply 2 number byte-size and the result is a word.
Thank you!

```
;Sa se scrie un program in limbaj de asamblare 
;care sa rezolve expresia aritmetica
; [d-2*(a-b)+b*c]/2, unde
;a,b,c sunt de tip-byte, iar d-de tip word

ASSUME ds:data,cs:code

data segment
a db 9
b db 5
c db 5
d dw 1155
rez dw ?
data ends

code segment
start:
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax
mov al,a ; al:=a
sub al,b ; al=al-b
mov ah,0
mov bx,d
sub bx,ax
sub bx,ax
mov al,b
mul c
add bx,ax
mov ax,bx
mov cx,2
div cx
mov rez,ax
int 21h
code ends
end start
```

Comment: and this error is...?

Comment: the result is not good...for example 5*5 is 25 and in h is not 19..the computer tells me that this result 19h and it is not

Comment: uh, 25 decimal is 19 hex... computers don't work in decimal, and you're not using the BCD functions.

Comment: but i stiil have an erro in code..and i can't find it...The final result saved in "rez" is with 10 less and normal

Comment: Thank you! My mistake...!!:)

Comment: Please also note that "div cx" does not divide AX by CX but it divides DX:AX by CX. If DX is not 0 you may get a wrong result or even a "Division Exception". Dividing by 2 can be done more efficiently using the "SHR" instruction.